# Snap2html for Ubuntu?

Tags: alternative, snapshot

There is a wonderful program created by rlvision.com called snap2html. It creates a very intuitive and visual snapshot of all the files and directories in a certain directory. I'm desperately looking for a similar program for Ubuntu. I couldn't find it online. I used to do that with `tree` and `aha`, but that's not nearly as compact and charming as snap2html.

Comment: I've written something like that for myself several month ago, but there is only source code available. If nothing else shows up and you feel comfortable compiling yourself in a QT environment- feel free to check out:  https://github.com/yafp/dirgister

Comment: Have you tried to run snap2html using [Wine](https://wiki.winehq.org/Main_Page)?

Comment: Yes, I did try to run it under `Wine`. It works. However, I wanted a native Linux application. Frankly, I'm surprised that there's not any.

Answer (score 2):

I'm responding to a very old post but this is for new searches.

I'm a huge fan and user of Snap2HTML. I transitioned to Linux fulltime several years ago and the only reason I run WINE is to be able to run Snap2HTML. That's how valuable it is to me.

Finally found a great replacement that use's Snap2HTML's template. It's called LinuxDir2HTML : https://github.com/homeisfar/LinuxDir2HTML

This is the reddit post that directed me to the python program: https://redd.it/hxz8ln

I tried every other solution that I found over then years and nothing ever came close to Snap2HTML until I turned up LinuxDir2HTML recently. This is the answer for anyone looking for a direct Snap2HTML solution on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

DiogenesList is a [nice command-line clone](https://github.com/ZapperDJ/DiogenesList/) of Snap2HTML. You simply download the python script and run the command as such in the terminal:

```
python diogeneslist.py /directory/you/want/to/scan nameofoutputfile
```

It will create a file named nameofoutputfile.html in your current directory that looks just like the file created by Snap2HTML.

Comment: Can you explain a little how works this package?